# Why isn't adding a path to ".profile" working?

Tags: lubuntu, environment-variables

I am using Lubuntu 12.04.

I am having problems setting the path variable for my application.

I am trying to set the path variable in the .profile file, however after adding the path when I echo $PATH, it does not show my addition.

Here is the line I am adding at the end of the .profile after the 'fi'

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/treedev/lib/Qt/bin
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong. When I run the above command directly in the bash shell, it works, which leads me to believe I am doing something wrong, but I can't seem to figure out where I am wrong.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a system-wide path, simply add to the PATH variable defined in `/etc/environment`.

1. Press `Alt+F2` and type `gksudo gedit /etc/environment`
2. Change the default path:

   ```
   PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
   ```

   by adding your path to it:

   ```
   PATH:"/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/treedev/lib/Qt/bin"
   ```

To add this path only to your session (i.e. for your user only), add to `~/.pam_environment` instead:

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/treedev/lib/Qt/bin
```

> Related: Please see the [Ubuntu Wiki on Environment Variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Session-wide_environment_variables).

Answer (score 0):

type the command below to load the path

```
source ~/.profile
```

Next time onward when the when the user log in it will auto load the path. But I would recommend you the add the path to /etc/profile.